# Mochiweb + AMQP consumer concurrently

Tags: erlang, scalability, message-queue, amqp

I'm new to Erlang and have been reading O'Reilly's great book, I've followed some tutorials on the Internetz as well. I can get my basic Mochiweb chat like application working stand alone and also get a basic bit of code to consume from an AMQP queue running.

My issue now comes in that I want to have all of this running together. However I'm confused in the code generated by mochiweb using (make app PROJECT=projname PREFIX=$HOME/PROJECT/) where I can kick off my AMQP consumer.

I plan to have a bit of code to "route" the messages from AMQP to the mochiweb chat like application I've built. I also want to be able to spawn multiple consumers and routers so that I can scale if necessary.

Can someone give me some advice on structuring my project? Where would I start my consumer? in the projname.erl start() -> bit?

Most of the stuff I've read is great at introducing syntax and concepts but the how to build a decent scalable architecture with Erlang is the bit I'm struggling with. I guess you'll say to go and read the Joe Armstrong book which I don't have?

Answer (score 0):

Add your consumer to the supervisor that has been generated for your project, which should be projname_sup.erl.

In this module, you'll find the definition of a supervision tree that only contains a child named "Web":

```
init([]) ->
Web = web_specs(dnd_server_web, 8080),
Processes = [Web],
```

Just create supervisor specs for your AMQP consumer and add it to the Processes list.